function calling enforcing azure openai
I'm using function calling. I have 2 : preferred and alternative date. The agent should ask for preferred date and then ask for alternative after receiving the first one.
def prepare_functions(self):
    """Prepare the functions that the agent can use during the conversation."""
    functions = [
        {
            "type": "function",
            "function": {
                "name": "end_call",
                "description": "End the call only when user explicitly requests it.",
                "parameters": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "message": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "The message you will say before ending the call with the customer.",
                        },
                    },
                    "required": ["message"],
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "type": "function",
            "function": {
                "name": "create_workload",
                "description": "Create a workload incorporating the user's availabilities",
                "parameters": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "workflow": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "The workload JSON that describes the actions to be taken, including availability details.",
                        },
                    },
                    "required": ["workflow"],
                },
            },
        },
        {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "ask_preferred_availability",
            "description": "Ask the user for their preferred availability",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The message to ask the user about their preferred availability.",
                    },
                },
                "required": ["message"],
            },
        },
       },
       {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "ask_alternative_availability",
            "description": "Ask the user for an alternative availability.",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The message to ask the user about their alternative availability.",
                    },
                },
                "required": ["message"],
            },
        },
    }

    ]
    return functions

The agent call preferred availability function, but doesn't call alternative availability. I tried using state and change the state when the user provide the preferred availability, but it doesn't work.

Please share the code and steps which you have tried so far.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Harshitha , thanks for your reply. I have added the code. Eveythng work but my problem is i want the agent after asking for prefered availability , it should automatically ask again for alternative availability.

You can use the given code to get the response from agent. I have used Azure Function here.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state="ask_preferred"):
        self.state = state  
        self.preferred_availability = None
        self.alternative_availability = None

    def prepare_functions(self):
        """Prepare the functions that the agent can use during the conversation."""
        functions = [
            {
                "type": "function",
                "function": {
                    "name": "end_call",
                    "description": "End the call only when user explicitly requests it.",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "message": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The message you will say before ending the call with the customer.",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["message"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "function",
                "function": {
                    "name": "create_workload",
                    "description": "Create a workload incorporating the user's availabilities",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "workflow": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The workload JSON that describes the actions to be taken, including availability details.",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["workflow"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "function",
                "function": {
                    "name": "ask_preferred_availability",
                    "description": "Ask the user for their preferred availability",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "message": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The message to ask the user about their preferred availability.",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["message"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "function",
                "function": {
                    "name": "ask_alternative_availability",
                    "description": "Ask the user for an alternative availability.",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "message": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The message to ask the user about their alternative availability.",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["message"],
                    },
                },
            }
        ]
        return functions

    def handle_response(self, user_response):
        """Handle the user response and call the appropriate functions."""
        if self.state == "ask_preferred":
            self.preferred_availability = user_response
            print(f"Received preferred availability: {self.preferred_availability}")
            self.state = "ask_alternative"
            return {
                "function": "ask_alternative_availability",
                "message": "Could you please provide an alternative date as well?",
                "next_state": self.state
            }

        elif self.state == "ask_alternative":
            self.alternative_availability = user_response
            print(f"Received alternative availability: {self.alternative_availability}")
            return {
                "function": "create_workload",
                "workflow": f"Preferred: {self.preferred_availability}, Alternative: {self.alternative_availability}",
                "next_state": self.state
            }

    def call_function(self, function_name, params):
        """Simulate calling a function with the given parameters."""
        return f"Calling function: {function_name} with params: {params}"

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        user_response = req_body.get('response')
        agent_state = req_body.get('state', 'ask_preferred') 

        agent = Agent(state=agent_state)
        action = agent.handle_response(user_response)
        
        result = agent.call_function(action['function'], action)

        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                "result": result,
                "next_state": action.get('next_state', agent.state)
            }),
            status_code=200,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error processing the request: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error processing the request",
            status_code=400
        )

I am getting below response.

